# Find the rank of a user's lowest lap time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a number of race car drivers, that race at different tracks. I want to get their best lap time at each particular track, and rank it against other users best lap times at that particular track. I want to do this for all users at all tracks. So I want to return a large leaderboard.

Basically, if I have 10 race car drivers that have each completed 25 laps at track #1 I want to identify only the best lap time of each race car driver and rank those times against one another, at each track.

I think I ALMOST have it, see query below and a SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64d6c/2

To make sure you have all the pieces, there is also a "tracks.verified" column. This determines whether or not the track has been verified. You don't really need to worry about this parameter and can leave it out if you want. I'm referring to this line:

```
AND s1.track_id IN (SELECT id FROM tracks WHERE verified=1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64d6c/2

```
SELECT track_id, user_id, duration, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT s1.track_id, s1.user_id, s1.duration
  FROM session_lap_times s1
  LEFT JOIN session_lap_times s2
    ON s1.user_id=s2.user_id
   AND s1.track_id = s2.track_id
   AND s1.duration > s2.duration
  WHERE s2.duration IS NULL
    AND s1.track_id IN (SELECT id FROM tracks WHERE verified=1)
  ORDER BY s1.duration ASC
) zz, (SELECT @rank := 0) z;
```

This outputs:

```
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
| track_id | user_id | duration         | rank |
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
|       15 |       2 | 71001.5129995350 |    1 |
|       15 |       1 | 75001.5129995350 |    2 |
|       17 |       1 | 90258.1180334090 |    3 |
|       17 |       2 | 90897.0659971240 |    4 |
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
```

The problem is its ranking all against each other, and not against all by each track. These results should look like this:

```
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
| track_id | user_id | duration         | rank |
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
|       15 |       2 | 71001.5129995350 |    1 |
|       15 |       1 | 75001.5129995350 |    2 |
|       17 |       1 | 90258.1180334090 |    1 |
|       17 |       2 | 90897.0659971240 |    2 |
+----------+---------+------------------+------+
```

I think this line is the problem:

```
AND s1.track_id IN (SELECT id FROM tracks WHERE verified=1)
```

Because if I put s1.track_id = 15 (for example), this works as expected for a single track. Just not them all.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I'm trying to filter the results by user_id. So I took your whole query and put it into a subquery. Is there any way to do this without putting it into a subquery? Thanks

```
select track_id, user_id, duration, rank from (SELECT track_id, user_id,duration, 
  CASE WHEN track_id!=@track THEN @rank:=0 END as reset,
  @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank,
  @track:=track_id
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT s1.track_id, s1.user_id, s1.duration
  FROM session_lap_times s1
  LEFT JOIN session_lap_times s2
    ON s1.user_id=s2.user_id
   AND s1.track_id = s2.track_id
   AND s1.duration > s2.duration
  WHERE s2.duration IS NULL
    AND s1.track_id IN (SELECT id FROM tracks WHERE verified=1)
  ORDER BY s1.duration ASC
) zz, (SELECT @rank := 0, @track := null) z) as x where user_id=1
```

As for counting the total number of drivers query I've got:

```
SELECT track_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM (SELECT track_id,user_id FROM session_lap_times GROUP BY track_id,user_id) as z GROUP BY track_id
```

Again, is there a nicer way of doing this without the subquery? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT track_id, user_id, duration, 
  CASE WHEN track_id!=@track THEN @rank:=0 END as reset,
  @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank,
  @track:=track_id
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT s1.track_id, s1.user_id, s1.duration
  FROM session_lap_times s1
  LEFT JOIN session_lap_times s2
    ON s1.user_id=s2.user_id
   AND s1.track_id = s2.track_id
   AND s1.duration > s2.duration
  WHERE s2.duration IS NULL
    AND s1.track_id IN (SELECT id FROM tracks WHERE verified=1)
  ORDER BY s1.duration ASC
) zz, (SELECT @rank := 0, @track := null) z;
```

Tested with your fiddle.

Introduce an additional variable and reset `rank` on `track_id` change

Comment: OH wow. Awesome!! Is it possible to get a rank "out of" value returned as well? A total of all drivers that have raced at that track? So I can display something like this in my app: rank 1 out of 2000 drivers? Let me know if its not appropriate to do this in the same query, and if it should rather have its own query.

Comment: After further thought, I'm thinking it might be easier to do it in a separate query. Then match the results up in my app code later. Do you know of a query that could do this? Thanks!

Comment: In the original query you posted is there a way to filter the results by user_id? So for example, user_id 1 should have rank 1 at track_id 17, and rank 2 at track_id 15.

Comment: Yes. There should be proper ORDER BY to define the order and then rank could be calculated

Comment: Hey, it turns out that query hasn't completely solved the problem. When I added more sample data it reset the ranking. Can you take a look? 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da399

I'll create a new stackoverflow question in a minute so you can get more points!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590601/finding-the-rank-of-a-users-fastest-lap-time

Comment: somehow sqlfiddle can't execute the query... throws "oops something wrong happened..."

Comment: Ah I think I just figured it out anyway. I added an ORDER BY track_id,duration to the very end of the query. It seems to display correctly now.

Comment: any chance you can explain the s2.duration is NULL bit? I"m trying to add a date range to this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da399/10 where the timestamp is a unix timestamp * 1000 (for milliseconds)

Comment: So that I can show the rankings for the day, as opposed to just overall.

Comment: the s2.duration is NULL is from your query from your question

Answer (score 0):

I find your SQL confusing. I would use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT track_id, user_id, MIN(duration) as best_time
FROM session_lap_times
GROUP BY track_id, user_id
ORDER BY track_id, best_time;
```